# How do I install a package to an existing docker image?

Tags: docker

I am running docker. I like to use an rhel7 image. The rhel7 image does not have certain package that I need. Let say app `XYZ`. I would like to include `XYZ` to the RHEL7 image. How would I do this ?
Do I startup rhel7 container, attach to the container, and download  the `XYZ` app to the running container? Do I download to my local machine and somehow have the container points the local machine ? I will appreciate any example.

Comment: You use a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) based on the RHEL7 image to create a *new* image that has the packages you need. You'll find lots of examples of building container images online; e.g. [here](https://devopscube.com/build-docker-image/).

Answer (score 0):

Before explaining to you how this works this is a great read about:
[What are Docker image "layers"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222377/what-are-docker-image-layers)

First, you will need to get inside your running container and install the package you need which is:

```
yum install XYZ -y
```

Once the package is installed you can exit from the container with `exit` in shell

Now you can create a new image from this docker container which we just exited:

```
docker commit container_name/id rhelWithMyCustomPackage(XYZ)
```

And done. now this new image rhelWithMyCustomPackage contains your Package which can run after spawning is new container using this image.

To transfer this image say a different Docker host you can use a platform like dockerhub which can maintain docker images for you.

If you read the article I shared above it speaks about these docker images being a read-only entity. This means if suppose you want to recreate this image from the start your Dockerfile will look like this:

```
FROM rhel7
RUN yum install XYZ
```

Then you again build this image:

```
docker build -t rhelWithMyCustomPackage .
```

And start a new container.

Hope I have explained everything in a crisp and understandable manner. Thanks.

Comment: You should almost never use `docker commit`.  Imagine there's some security issue in the base RHEL layer and you need to recreate the image, but it's been a year since you built it; will you remember the exact set of commands you ran to create the image the first time?